# Use input capture for multiple sensors simultaneously

Tags: interrupt, timers

I want to accurately time multiple digital input channels (readings from sensors) for the rising and falling edges. I need the precision of the Timer1 Input Capture. As far as I know the input capture only listens to pin D8 (for ATmega8). So, is there anyway to capture the inputs of multiple sensors?

---

Update:

I would like the reading to be as accurate as possible since I'm using the values to calculate motion tracking information. Concretely, I'm trying to build my own tracker for [StreamVR's light house](http://gizmodo.com/this-is-how-valve-s-amazing-lighthouse-tracking-technol-1705356768).

Comment: How accurately? (in microseconds)

Comment: As accurate as possible... see my edited question. BTW, I've read your note on Arduino's interrupt... That is very valuable! Thanks! :D

Comment: "As accurately as possible" is too vague. You may as well say you want to have "as much money as possible" in a job interview. Do you want accuracy down to 1 ns? 1 µs? 1 ms? 10 ms? Let's say your answer is "1 ns". Then the ATmega8 isn't the chip for you.

Comment: If you use pin-change interrupts, then you will get "as much accuracy as possible" that pin-change interrupts will give you.

Comment: Then you better use the ATmega328P, because the ATmega8 doesn't have "PCINT" (Pin Change Interrupt).
Some older sensors use frequency output, because a microcontroller could read that. However, today there is I2C and SPI interface. If you can't get another interface than a frequency output and you want the best accuracy, then you have to add extra hardware to read those signals.

Comment: If you want input capture (i.e. single cycle) accuracy on multiple input channels, you will need multiple input capture units. The Atmega2560 (powering the Arduino Mega 2560) has four of them, one in each 16-bit timer.